# Add ACF Quick Edit Columns on Comments

Tags: comments, advanced-custom-fields, quick-edit

I'm using ACF to add a custom field to all comments. It's an optional checkbox with categories that the commenter can use to categorize their comment, which we use for filtering later on.

From within the Edit Comment page in wp-admin, I'm able to see what was checked and edit it if need be.

How can I  also add this feature to the quick edit options while viewing all comments? I'd like to be able to quickly categorize the comment from this page without having to click in to every comment individually.

Comment: You should open a support request with ACF; third party plugins are off topic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.